# How to get displayed decimal place

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How to return the displayed decimal place only in excel by formula? for example, A1=9.123, it formated to display 9.12; how to get the decimal number of 2 in this case;

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like...

```
=INT(((A1*10)-INT(A1*10))*10)
```

This takes (91.23-91), which gives 0.23 and times 10 to give 2.3 and turns it into an integer: 2, or

```
=INT(A1*100)-(10*INT(A1*10))
```

This one takes 912 minus 10*(91)=910, giving 2, or even:

```
=MID(A1,4,1)*1
```

This one treats the number as a string and takes the 4th character (position 4, taking 1 character) and the `*1` is to convert the string back to number.

You also can have:

```
=INT(MOD(A1*100,10))
```

Which takes 910, the remaider when divided by 10 which is 2.3 and taking the integer of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want decimal number 2 in B1:

=ROUND((A1-ROUND(A1,**1**))***100**,0)

The logic of the formula are as follows:

1) 9.123 - ROUND(9.123,1) = 9.123 - 9.1 = 0.023

2) 0.023 * 100 = 2.3

3) ROUND(2.3,0)

You can thus tweak the formula in the bold bits to change the decimal returned.

Comment: The downside with `ROUND()` is that it can also round _up_, which might not be desireable if the number was... say `9.153` or `9.125`. Still, since it works for `9.123` :)

Comment: Ah! I assumed that since roundup() and rounddown() existed that it would work - at least I learnt the existence of int() now though :)

Comment: You can still use `ROUNDDOWN()` for this problem, and it will act similar to `INT()` here ^^

Answer (score 0):

If A1 contains 9.123, then in B1 type in

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,2),1)
```

This will give you 2.